# How to prevent pd.concat from inserting `.1` after columns with the same name?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to merge 2 datasets together where column names overlap.

for example like this:

```
df1:

col1   col2
aa     aa
bb     bb

df2:
col2   col3
cc     dd

new_df = pd.concat([df1,df2],axis=1)

new_df:

    col1   col2    col3
    aa     aa
    bb     bb
           cc     dd
```

When I run the above line in my code I get something like this:

```
  col1   col2   col2.1   col3
    aa     aa     nan
    bb     bb     nan
           cc     nan     dd
```

How do I prevent the `.1` from appearing and force pd.concat to match the column names and insert data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You concatenated along the *wrong* axis. here you used the *column* axis, whereas you want to concatenate over the *index* axis:

```
>>> pd.concat([df1, df2], axis='rows')
  col1 col2 col3
0   aa   aa  NaN
1   bb   bb  NaN
0  NaN   cc   dd
```

So by either specifying `axis=0`, `axis='rows'`, `axis='index'`, or omitting it totally, the columns are "grouped", and you concatenate "vertically".